# Pulling out quotes from within a text file

Tags: python, xml, string, list

Let's say I have a text file in python that says:

```
the data starts
test Age="0" Order="51" Doctor-ID="XX2342"
test Age="0" Order="53" Doctor-ID="XX2342"
end of data
```

What code would return:

```
"0" "51" "XX2342"
"0" "53" "XX2342"
```

Returning lists would also work.

```
[["0","51","XX2342"]
["0","53","XX2342"]]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.*?` or `[^"]*`, so that it would match also the double quotes which contains an empty string.

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '"' in line:
            print re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', line)
```

**OR**

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '"' in line:
            print re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', line)
```

Comment: This is excellent. However, it is leaving it all as one list.

Would it be possible to make each line its own list?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect job for regex

```
line = 'test Age="0" Order="51" Doctor-ID="XX2342"'
import re
re.findall('"(.*?)"', line)
>>> ['0', '51', 'XX2342']
```

For operating on multiple lines:

```
lines = '''
test Age="0" Order="51" Doctor-ID="XX2342"
test Age="0" Order="53" Doctor-ID="XX2342"
'''
results = []
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    result = re.findall('"(.*?)"', line)
    if result:
        results.append(result)

for result in results:
    print result
```

This gives:

```
['0', '51', 'XX2342']
['0', '53', 'XX2342']
```

Comment: Ok. I just ran the code, but it seems to fail if I have a case
`test Age="0" Order="53" Doctor-ID="XX2342" Work="" Condition="Good"`

It returns `['0', '53', 'XX2342', '", Condition=']`

Comment: If you need to deal with blackslash-escaped quotes, you could use the (somewhat scarier) regex `r'"((?:[^"]|\\")+?)"'`

Comment: Oops, then just use  `'"(.*?)"'` instead

Comment: @Andy with everything being as one list this works perfect!

Any way to make each line its own list?

It could, of course, be a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [
    'test Age="0" Order="51" Doctor-ID="XX2342"',
    'test Age="0" Order="53" Doctor-ID="XX2342"'
]

for line in lines: 
    l = line.split('"')[1::2]
    print l
```

Prints:

```
['0', '51', 'XX2342']
['0', '53', 'XX2342']
```

---

Explanation:

I am splitting each line at your quotation marks. I then pull the odd elements of the split using [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

With slicing, the notation is `start:end:step`. For this, we are starting at index 1, continuing to the end, and stepping two indexes each time. This will pull items within quotes.

If you have escaped quotes, this method will not work as expected.

Very quick example of slicing (with a bonus [tutorial link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice)):

```
>>> L = range(10)
>>> L[1::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

>>> L = range(10)
>>> L[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```